How to declare a common dependency for all subprojects?
Facing this issue with dependency injecting libraries. All subprojects have a di and i have to declare DI library every time. Is there a better way?

Write a convention plugin.
I described how to write a precompiled script plugin in detail in another answer.
To specifically add a common dependency across Android projects, you would need to:

Include the Android library plugin JAR1 as a dependency of the buildSrc project in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts:

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.5.0")
}



Write the shared build code in the plugin script file, say buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/library.gradle.kts:

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}

dependencies {
    // Add shared dependencies
}



Then you can apply the shared plugin in the library modules. You no longer need to apply the Android library plugin either.

plugins {
    library // Gradle auto-generates an accessor for the new plugin
}


1 Assuming you are only targeting Android libraries with your shared build code. If you are targeting applications as well you will of course need the Android Application Gradle plugin JAR as well and either create more than one shared plugin or have your single plugin declare a function which can be called inside the build script of an applying project to apply either the Android Application or Library plugin.
